# Foreach loop not running through list of entries

Tags: powershell, loops, foreach, scripting

I've tried searching this multiple times but havent resolved the issue. I have a list of servers in $mediaagentlist, the foreach loop is supposed to run through each one and get the state of certain services:

```
    $mediaagentlist = "cs0400ma01
cs0400ma02"

[string]$Commcell_Input = $args[0] 
$MAChoice = $args[1]

if ($MAChoice -eq $null)
        {
            Write-Output "No media agent was specified, running against all MAs in the Commcell..."

            #Run this loop for each MA which is stored in Mediaagentlist
            foreach ($Mediaagent in $Mediaagentlist)
            {
                Write-Output $Mediaagent
                $GxCLMgrS_State = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Mediaagent {Get-Service -name "GxClMgrS(Instance001)"}
                $GXMMM_State = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Mediaagent {Get-Service -name "GXMMM(Instance001)"}
                $GxCVD_State = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Mediaagent {Get-Service -name "GxCVD(Instance001)"}

                Write-Output "Client manager service state: " $GxCLMgrS_State.Status
                Write-Output "Media manager mount service state: " $GXMMM_State.Status
                Write-Output "Communications service state: " $GxCVD_State.Status

            }


        }
```

How do I correct this so the for each loop runs through the list of entries in $mediaagentlist and runs the code for each server?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your `mediaagentlist` variable is not an array.  It's a single string so there's nothing to iterate over.  To use arrays, you need commas: `$mediaAgentList = 'cs0400ma01', 'cs0400ma02'`

Comment: make an array out of $mediaagentlist like: $mediaagentlist = @("cs0400ma01", "cs0400ma02")

Comment: Amazing, that worked! That makes sense now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your issue is here

```
$mediaagentlist = "cs0400ma01
cs0400ma02"
```

It looks like your missing a closing qoute per word and a comma

try

```
$mediaagentlist = "cs0400ma01", "cs0400ma02"
```

or

```
$mediaagentlist = @("cs0400ma01", "cs0400ma02")
```

Or you can define a multi-line string, then split on new lines, if there's a reason you needed the input to be a single multi-line string:

```
$mediaagentlist = "cs0400ma01
cs0400ma02" -split '[\r\n]+'
```

Comment: `-split "\`r?\`n"` **

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 You have some of the best advice

Comment: An informed community is a better community  I run into issues where line endings may not be predictable pretty often.